# How to deploy local maven repo to remote repo

Tags: maven

I've a valid local maven repo which is generated by a closed-source tool. I'd like to deploy the full repo to a remote maven repo.

Any clues how to do this ?

Comment: You want the _whole_ repository deployed?  Or just one or a few artifacts?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Yes the whole repo.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't scp or transfer up the repo another way, then I assume you'd have to write a script that would walk your local repo and put them all up using the deploy plugin.
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html

If you're moving the whole repo up, I'd suggest to put it to an isolated repo so that it doesn't mix with other upstream repos like central.

Comment: Yes that is my current approach since Github Package Registry does not support scp protocol. Thanks